# i can't get an output from this

Tags: c++, stack

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class stack
{

 int size=10;

 int stack[size]={0}, value=0, top;

 top=size;

 public:

         void push(int v)
         {
          if(top==0)
            cout<<"\nstack is full\n";
          else
            {--top;
            stack[top]=v;}
            }

         void pop()
          {
            if(top==size)
               cout<<"\nstack is empty\n";
             else
             {top++;
              stack[top];
              stack[top-1]=0;
               }
            }

       void display()
         {
            if(top==size)
              cout<<"\nstack empty\n";
            else
              {
                for(int i=top;i<size-1;i++)
                {
                 cout<<stack[i];
                   }
               }
              }
};

int main()

{

 stack s;

 char t;

 int value,ch;

 do

 {

 cout<<"\n1.push\n";

 cout<<"\n2.pop\n";

 cout<<"\n3.display\n";

 cout<<"enter choice:\n";

 cin>>ch;

 switch(ch)

 {

  case 1:cout<<"\nenter the value to be pushed\n";

         cin>>value;

         s.push(value);

         break;

  case 2:s.pop();

          break;

  case 3:s.display();

          break;

  default:

         cout<<"\nwrong choice\n";

 }

 cout<<"\ndo u want to retry\n";

 cin>>t;

 }while(t=='y' || t=='Y');

return 0;

}
```

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Comment: Could you specify what input do you give to the program and what output you expect?

Comment: actually errors are occuring

Comment: stackc.cpp:6:12: error: invalid use of non-static data member ‘stack::size’
  int stack[size]={0},value=0,top;

Comment: stackc.cpp:7:2: error: ‘top’ does not name a type
  top=size;

Comment: stackc.cpp: In member function ‘void stack::push(int)’:
stackc.cpp:15:18: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘[’ token
             stack[top]=v;}
                  ^

Comment: stackc.cpp: In member function ‘void stack::pop()’:
stackc.cpp:24:20: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘[’ token
               stack[top];
                    ^

Comment: stackc.cpp:25:20: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘[’ token
               stack[top-1]=0;
                    ^
stackc.cpp: In member function ‘void stack::display()’:
stackc.cpp:37:29: error: expected primary-expression before ‘[’ token
                  cout<<stack[i];
                             ^

Comment: my above comment are the errors occuring

Comment: Those should be included in the question, not in comments. Please edit the question. BTW, those are compiler errors - your program does not even compile, let alone running, so how could you expect to get any OUTPUT from it is beyond me...

Answer (score 1):

Simplest fix to errors occurring is changing `int size=10;` to `static const int size=10;`.
After this, apart from occurring warning with `stack[top];` being empty statement, there is logical error in `display` loop in `for(int i=top;i<size-1;i++)` where it should be either `for(int i=top;i<size;i++)` or `for(int i=top;i<=size-1;i++)`.

Answer (score 0):

As answered by Tomáš Zahradníček, you need to fix a few things to have your code compile (using -std=c++11).

I used `for(int i=top; i<size; ++i)` in the `display` method. I also add that your `pop` method could simply do `top++;` without overwriting the stack.

Anyways, regarding your problem of nothing being printed on cout : you obviously tried with 1 item pushed in the stack, but not with 2, which would have pointed to faulty line (the `for` loop).

Comment: I had written the display ();

Comment: Does your code compile now? Do you (re)produce the error? What inputs do you give your executable?

Comment: My program is not compiling

Comment: Perhaps you should update your initial message, with the current status.